# Exclude some items from minimum order rule

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, ce-1.9.1.0, price-rules

Is possible to exclude some SKUs from minimum order amount?

For example: Our limit for minimum order is 30$ and we don't want to include items #1, #2 and #3 into this limit because they are only bonus for customers..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does anyone know please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found module which contain fuction I need.
It charges fee if order amount is less than minimum and I can exclude my bonus products.

https://github.com/unleashedtech/min-order-fee-magento

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the `validateMinimumAmount` in the class `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Address.php`

Currently it works like

```
    $amount = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/amount', $storeId);
    if ($this->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() < $amount) {
        return false;
    }
```

but you can increase the amount for each specific item like

```
    $amount = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/amount', $storeId);
    foreach($this->getAllItems() as $item){
        if(in_array($item->getSku(), array("spacial item #1", "spacial item #2")))
        $amount += $item->getPrice(); 
    }
```

so the next condition will "skip" them

```
    if ($this->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() < $amount) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you please give the whole code how it should look like? I'm unable to make this working. Cheers

Comment: do you have any errors?  You can copy the Address.php (with folders) into the /local/ code base and make direct chnages without creating a new module and rewriting the model.

Comment: I'm actually editing the magento core at testing website. But the problem is I don't quite understand that function. This is what I did `$amount = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/amount', $storeId);
    foreach($this->getAllItems() as $item){
        if(in_array($item->getSku(), array("spacial item #1", "spacial item #2")))
        $amount += $item->getPrice(); 
    }

        if ($this->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() < $amount) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }` But it doesn't work. No errors.

Comment: did you set your SKUs?

Comment: Sure, I did. But I guess I have combined those 2 function incorrectly.